# Map don't process if condition is true

Tags: ruby

This is pretty basic, but I'm not sure how to do this unless if I use array inside map, which is lame.

I need to get this:

```
"T--- is my d-- b-- n-- y---"
```

If there are two characters I need to skip it, not to process it but still keep it. If I use `next`, I get nil.

```
str = "This is my day but not your"

str.split.map{ |word| word[0] + word[1..-1].gsub(/./,"-")} * " " #=> T--- i- m- d-- b-- n-- y---
```

This is my second solution, which I don’t like, but it works, I'm sure there is more elegant solution:

```
arr = Array.new
str.split.map{ |word| 
arr << word if word.length < 3
arr << word[0] + word[1..-1].gsub(/./,"-")} * " "

puts  arr.join(" ")
```

Comment: What happens if a word is one character, such as "a" or "I"?

Comment: Thanks for contributing TinMan, I like your solution. If a word is single character, it will not be replaced, and I don’t want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Just do an identity mapping on cases when you don't want to do anything.

```
str.split.map{ |word|
  if word.length == 2
    word
  else
    word[0] + word[1..-1].gsub(/./,"-")
  end
} * " "
```

If you need a one-liner:

```
str.split.map{ |word| word.length == 2 ? word : word[0] + word[1..-1].gsub(/./,"-")} * " "
```

Comment: It seams I don’t understand map, thanks! I came up with this.

   str.split.map{ |word| word if word.length < 3 ; word[0] + word[1..-1].gsub(/./,"-")} * " "

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
str = "This is my day but not your"
ary = str.split.map{ |s| 
  if s.size != 2
    s[0] + '-' * (s.size - 1)
  else
    s
  end
}
```

Here's what `ary` looks like:

```
ary
# => ["T---", "is", "my", "d--", "b--", "n--", "y---"]
```

`join` the arrays to recreate a string:

```
ary.join(' ')
# => "T--- is my d-- b-- n-- y---"
```

---

> What happens if a word is one character, such as "a" or "I"?
>
> If a word is single character, it will not be replaced, and I don’t want it to be.

```
str = "This is my day but not your a"
ary = str.split.map{ |s| 
  if s.size > 2
    s[0] + '-' * (s.size - 1)
  else
    s
  end
}

ary
# => ["T---", "is", "my", "d--", "b--", "n--", "y---", "a"]

ary.join(' ')
# => "T--- is my d-- b-- n-- y--- a"
```

Comment: This is awesome, couple month ago if someone told me I would admire to a code, I would though he's crazy.

Comment: "Elegance" is a concept in programming, which is code that is simple, easy to read, yet powerful. I don't claim to write code that is elegant, but I try. I find that Ruby lends itself nicely to elegance though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a more specific regular expression with `gsub` on the string as a whole so that you're only processing words of three characters or longer.

```
str.gsub(/\w{3,}/) do |word| 
 word[0]<<word[1..-1].gsub(/./,'-')}
end
```

In the outer `gsub`, `\w` refers to any "word" character (mostly letters and numbers). `{3,}` means repeated at least 3 times. In the block, we do another gsub to process the individual word.

You could probably do this in a single `gsub` using a complex regular expression with lookbehind and lookahead, but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear about what the rules are for your substitutions, but one assumes that your rules are:

1. Print any word with two or less letters without modification.
2. Replace all characters except the first letter of each remaining word with an underscore.

With those rules, you can do this with code like the following:

```
str = 'This is my day but not yours'
str.split.map do |word|
  underscores = ?_ * (word.size - 1)
  word.size < 3 ? word : word.gsub(/\A.\K.*/, underscores)
end.join " "
#=> "T___ is my d__ b__ n__ y____"
```

There's certainly more than one way to do this, but this way seems both readable and extensible to me. Your mileage may vary.